# openshift - php application - best practise

Tags: php, .htaccess, openshift

I am developing a php, mysql application on openshift. I am a little new to php and openshift. I was wondering if someone could provide some information on good practices ( for example security related, or must-have configuration in the htaccess file) so that it is of an 'acceptable level'. I am have been researching this high and low but a few words of advise from the experts will be greatly beneficial. I would not want to learn the wrong way :-)

For example I can enfore HTTPS in htaccess. What else are the essentials that I shouldn't miss?

Comment: I didn't want it to be opinion-based or a super lengthy thread and that's the reason I used words like 'essentials' and 'acceptable level'. I do not work for the most secretive organisation in the world and I don't need a divine ensemble of warriors to protect. Let me try to explain this - Say I am in new(alien?) territory and I am opening a jewelry shop, all I want to know is what is a must-have protection for a jewelry shop in that region - a sword, a pistol or a machine gun? If someone tells me I need Howitzers, well....!!! Neel's post absolutely doesn't look opinion-based ",)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about openshift, i can give you some basic security tips for php,

**Preventing sql injecton:**

1. Use PDO class and prepared statement.
2. Set names to utf8 for database coneection.
3. Use mysql version 5.5+

**Prevent XSS:**

4. Use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to output your data on html pages.

**Prevent CSRF:**

5. Use csrf token and if possible use https protocol to prevent man i the middle attack.

**htaccess**

6. Write `Deny from all` to prevent access in your php folders.
7. Allow some specific IP address for your admin page.

Hope this helps...